# How to prevent double elements when merging include files in xsd?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am working on a stylesheet that processes some XSDs.
The main XSD file includes 2 others. Of those 2 one also includes the other.
All XSDs have the same attributes and namespaces in the root element. The files are only separate for maintenance purposes.

The stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:exa="http://www.example.com/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs exa">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="iso-8859-1" />

  <!-- global variable to merge schema with it's includes 
       to be used for further processing the schema -->

  <xsl:variable name="with_includes">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/xs:schema" mode="include"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- copy the main schema root element including attributes
       then process all nodes in it -->

  <xsl:template match="xs:schema" mode="include">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="include"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- all schemas have the same namespaces and targetnamespace defined 
       so do not copy namespaces -->

  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="include">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- when matching an include, process all the nodes in the schema -->

  <xsl:template match="xs:include" mode="include">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc(@schemaLocation)/xs:schema/node()" mode="include"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- only here to show the result -->

  <xsl:template match="/xs:schema">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$with_includes"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Some very basic example schemas to demonstrate the problem:

Schema A.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema 
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/example"
  xmlns:exa="http://www.example.com/example">

  <xs:include schemaLocation="B.xsd"/>
  <xs:include schemaLocation="C.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="a" type="exa:t_a"/>

  <xs:complexType name="t_a">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="b" type="exa:t_b"/>
      <xs:element name="c" type="exa:t_c"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Schema B.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema 
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/example"
  xmlns:exa="http://www.example.com/example">

  <xs:include schemaLocation="C.xsd"/>

  <xs:complexType name="t_b">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="c1" type="exa:t_c"/>
      <xs:element name="c2" type="exa:t_c"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Schema C.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema 
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/example"
  xmlns:exa="http://www.example.com/example">

  <xs:simpleType name="t_c">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
      <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

If I use the stylesheet above, I get simpleType t_c twice in the result. I am looking for a way to prevent that.

Btw, I use Saxon.

Comment: If both B and C are included in A, you don't have to include C in B

Comment: Well you could try to get rid of duplicates the usual way it is done in XSLT, by grouping (`xsl:for-each-group`) global types, global elements and others on their name and then outputting only the first of each group. To keep it simple, I would probably merge first and then in a second step eliminate duplicates in the merged data. But generally the schema language is rather complex, I am not sure a simple XSLT stylesheet can handle it. Saxon EE comes with http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!schema-processing/scm to produce a simpler representation but I have never used it.

Comment: @Tobias. True, but if you are processing schema A, you do not yet know that schema B also uses schema C. So when you go through schema B, how should I know that C has already been included in A?

Comment: @Martin. That was basically what I thought of too. The complexity of the schema language is not really an issue in the merging I require. I only deal with simpleTypes and complexTypes. Any complexity within those is not something to deal with in the merging. I know of Saxon EE, but I am just playing with this as an exercise, and then Saxon EE is a bit expensive :-), so I stick to Saxon HE or older, but definitely Saxon (IMHO the best around).

Comment: @PeterHofman do you use schema B alone without schema A? If so, including C in B makes sense, but if you don't, including C in A should be sufficient for B to have access to C, so including C in B again is unnecessary. As it is at the moment you are including C in A twice.

Comment: You've already spent a lot more than the cost of a Saxon-EE license ;-)

Comment: Not sure how to interpret that, Michael.

Comment: @Tobias. It can be B will be used in another schema which does not include C itself, so the current includes make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deduplicating the includes is relatively straightforward, but it becomes more complex if you need to handle cycles as well - cycles of xs:includes are permitted in XSD, though the 1.0 spec isn't entirely clear on the point. If you're not concerned about cycles, just build a list of all the includes by transitive expansion using a recursive function, preferably calling resolve-uri() to resolve each @schemaLocation against its base URI, then remove duplicates from the list using distinct-values(). If you need to eliminate cycles, you'll need to pass a parameter to your recursive function indicating the route by which the document was reached, and ignore a document if it's already on the list. If you've got a copy of my book, there's an example of cycle detection in the section on xsl:call-template. But you may find the book too expensive too ;-(

Comment: Quite often I think about getting a copy of your book, but since I postpone buying it, I haven't got it yet....sorry ;-). On the other hand, any question I have had so far regarding XSLT has been answered either here or on the xsl mailing list (in the past), by the great community. And I learned a lot from other questions and answers on the xsl mailing list.